# Shacharit Lechatchila

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, moshe-feinstein, hanetz-sunrise

I have heard from a very reliable rav that Rabbi Moshe Feinstein held that the only shacharit lechatchila is vatikin. This means that davening shacharit before sunrise and after sunrise are equally Bedi Avad.

Is there a written source for this? Has anyone else heard the same?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the "_davening shacharit before sunrise and after sunrise are equally Bedi Avad_" conclusion R. Moshe Feinstein's, the very reliable rav's, or your own?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Tzvi. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hi, Tzvi. The Rambam held that way also regarding shacharit and goes so far to say that the mitzvah is to pray at netz even b'yachid! Ask your Rav...

Comment: That doesn't seem to collude with the Gemarah's explanation that allows a time span. I'd like to see the answer explain how it doesn't conflict with the Gemarah's analysis.

Comment: Cahas ve chalilah I should make any conclusion on my own. The reliable Rav that I am referring to is Rabbi Mendelsohn From Kehila Marine  Park Brooklyn, NY  who heard it from Rav Hillel David Shelitah in the name of Rav Moshe zatzal.

Comment: chacham Nisan, Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me where can I find the pesak of the Rambam? which book of the Rambam? Which chapter etc?

Comment: I don't think Rambam says so explicitly in the _Mishneh Torah_, but in his responsa (in [respunsum 180](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1731&pgnum=52) in the Blau edition), he says: "... והיותר ראוי ליחיד ולצבור לקרוא קרית שמע עם הנץ החמה".

Comment: @tzvi, It is in אגרות משה, exactly as you quote it. I'm trying to get the exact refence.